# How to create a JWT DRF consumer, with external provider?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, jwt, single-sign-on

I have to set up the API part of an application.

To summarize, there is a private oauth provider, a front-end angular app, and a django rest framework resource API. 
The Angular app is unaccessible if not logged, and redirect to the oauth provider. The user have to login there and is redirected to the front-end. 
So far so good, the provider give the front-end a JWT access token.

Then the front ask for resources to the DRF API providing the JWT. 
That's where I'm stuck, all the tutorials I find on google explain how to create your own provider. 
But I just want to get the token, check with the oauth provider that it's valid, login the user, provide the resources, and then logout the user until the next request.

If someone can give me some usefull tuto/doc/library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up creating my own custom authentication class extending BaseAuthentication (and custom user, user manager, ...) as I did not found any existing library.

If someone in interested in details, you can check the DRF documentation and many resources on the internet.

P.S. don't forget to extend authenticate_header is you want to return 401 with "raise AuthenticationFailed" and not 403 (for some reason).

Comment: Would you be able to share your code for the custom authenticator? It would be most helpful.